# ActionScript 3 If/ Else If Statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, actionscript-3, flash

I am following exactly this tutorial on

Youtube :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ohlrknEwobs&list=PLE10sFVGtI1ejzPFmX5CebHrTMhaCx2oI&index=31

The concept is to make an avoid-er game in which 3 objects fall vertically, one of which will increase point score, and the other two which will end the game.

I have created 4 objects within an array which are as follows:

`var:objects Array = [new BlueBird(),new RedBird(),new Goomba(),new Ham()]`

> // objects[0] = Is a Blue Bird which jumps to scene 3 ("Death Scene")
>
> // objects[1] = Is a Red Bird which jumps to scene 3 ("Death Scene")
>
> // objects[2] = Is a Goomba which jumps to scene 3 ("Death Scene")
>
> // objects[3] = Is an piece of Ham which adds Points

Here is the statement that I am having trouble with. I can't get the object[3], the piece of Ham, to test for else if statement. I coded in && objectsIndex == 3, but it did not work:

```
if((Pig.hit).hitTestObject(objects[objectsIndex]))
   {
        // Reset objects to y positions
      objects[objectsIndex].x = randomRange(0,3) * 50
      objects[objectsIndex].y = -50;
      
      stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,pressedButton);
      stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,CollisionSensor);
      stage.frameRate = 24;
      
      gotoAndStop(1,"GG WP");
      //trace ("you died!");
   }
else if((Pig.hit).hitTestObject(objects[objectsIndex]) && objectsIndex == 3)
    {
        
    score = score + 1;  //increase score by 1 point
        text1.text = String(score); // Score is now a string value
                                    // Since text1 is a text box, it must be denotated as a  string
        // Reset the objects to y positions
        objects[objectsIndex].x = randomRange(0,3) * 50;
        objects[objectsIndex].y = -50
    }
```

Here is the entire Projects Code for Reference:

```
    stop();

import flash.events.Event;

stage.focus = this;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, pressedButton);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, CollisionSensor);

var score:Number = 0;   //Player Score
var enemy_velocity:Number = 5;
var objects:Array = [new RedBird(),new Goomba,new BlueBird(),new Ham()];

// objects[0] is a RedBird
// objects[1] is a Goomba
// objects[2] is a BlueBird
// objects[3] is an piece of Ham

var objectsIndex:Number = randomRange(0,3);     //Randomizer
                                                //Picks a random array value
for (var i:int=0; i<objects.length; i++)
{
    objects[i].x = randomRange(0,3) * 50;
    objects[i].y = -50;
    
    //Brings objects to stage
    stage.addChild(objects[i]);
}


//Generate a ranodom number from minNum to maxNum including the endpoints
function randomRange(minNum:Number, maxNum:Number):Number
{
    return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNum - minNum + 1)) + minNum);
}


function CollisionSensor(e:Event)
{
    
    objects[objectsIndex].y = objects[objectsIndex].y + enemy_velocity;
    
    // check if enemy objects have gone past the bottom of the game screen
    if (objects[objectsIndex].y > stage.stageHeight)
    {
        objects[objectsIndex].y = -50; //Resets objects in array and parameters
                            // To enter frame in a repeated loop
                            
        //Randomizes a random x position for Objects
        var num:Number = randomRange(0,3);
        //This creates 4 random x positions - 0,50,100,150 To randomly place
        //The array objects in
        objects[objectsIndex].x = num * 50;
        
        // now pick a random object
        objectsIndex = randomRange(0,3);
        // objects[0] is a RedBird
        // objects[1] is a Goomba
        // objects[2] is a BlueBird
        // objects[3] is an piece of Ham
                                


                        
if(stage.frameRate <= 60)
{
    stage.frameRate = stage.frameRate + 5;
}
else
{
    stage.frameRate = 60;
    
    if (enemy_velocity <= 25)
    {
        enemy_velocity += 1; 
    }
    else
    {
        enemy_velocity = 25;
    }
  }
}

//check contanct with enemy objects



if((Pig.hit).hitTestObject(objects[objectsIndex]))
       {
            // Reset objects to y positions
          objects[objectsIndex].x = randomRange(0,3) * 50
          objects[objectsIndex].y = -50;
          
          stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,pressedButton);
          stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,CollisionSensor);
          stage.frameRate = 24;
          
          gotoAndStop(1,"GG WP");
          //trace ("you died!");
       }


else if((Pig.hit).hitTestObject(objects[objectsIndex]) && objectsIndex == 3)
        {
            
        score = score + 1;

//increase score by 1 point
        `text1.text = String(score);` // Score is now a string value
                                    // Since text1 is a text box, it must be denotated as a string
        // Reset the objects to y positions
        

objects[objectsIndex].x = randomRange(0,3) * 50;
            objects[objectsIndex].y = -50
        }
}


function pressedButton(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT && Pig.x >= 0)
    {
        Pig.x = Pig.x - 50;
    }
    else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT && Pig.x <= 150)
    {
        Pig.x = Pig.x + 50;
    }
}
```

Thank you, and as always, have a nice day :)

Comment: If you don't explain what the problem is we will have many trouble to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

You might have other issues with your code but this does look right

```
if((Pig.hit).hitTestObject(objects[objectsIndex]))
```

it should be..

```
if((Pig).hitTestObject(objects[0]))
```

where `objects[0]` would be the index in the array to access for testing against. But that might even have issues so get specific names of what you added on stage try this in your `for loop` that adds objects to stage

```
//Brings objects to stage
stage.addChild(objects[i]);
trace ("added object name : " + objects[i] );
```

Whatever name you got there is what you test against `if( (Pig).hitTestObject(namehere) )`

Comment: trace(" Ham " : + objects[3] )                                           if( (Pig).hitTestObject(Ham) ) ~ Something like this?